# A React component keeps getting rerendered

Tags: reactjs, getstream-io

[Screen recording here](https://capture.dropbox.com/T2iKjvkoKRYb9bm2)

The component passed to `Activity` prop below keeps getting re-rendered.

Inside `<Activity .../>` component, there's a textarea, collapsibles, etc., but when I switch browser tabs and come back, they all get reset. This means whatever comment the user was writing gets deleted.

```
        <SinglePost
          activityId={activityId}
          feedGroup="user"
          userId={authorId}
          Activity={(props) => {
            console.log(
              " ~ file: [activityId].js ~ line 52 ~ PostDetails ~ props",
              props
            );
            return (
              <Activity
               // ... props to Activity
              />
```

The `console.log` statement keeps getting rerun every time I switch browser tabs and come back, or even when I switch tabs of two localhost instances in another browser window. (Please check the screen recording at the top)

The code for the `<SinglePost .../>` component definition is [here](https://github.com/GetStream/react-activity-feed/blob/142561584400f9bf9632a5e7889f58495b9fcad3/src/components/SinglePost.tsx). It's from GetStream's `react-activity-feed` library.

I've also tried `useMemo` to no avail.

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Do you have something like `CodeSandbox`?

Comment: No, `react-activity-feed` library requires an API key and I cannot just copy the API key there. I couldn't reproduce a similar error without `<SinglePost .../>` component either.

Comment: Every time the parent component which renders the `SinglePost` is rendered, a new instance of `Activity` render prop function is created. It depends on what you want to do, but you could use `useCallback` or create a wrapper component which renders `Activity` and use `memo` and render the component in the parent...

Comment: @c0m1t I've actually used `useMemo` and passed `[props.activity]` in the second arg. It keeps being re-rendered even though `props.activity` did not change! (checked using JSON diff checker) It only stopped re-rendering when I passed `[props.activity.id]` which is not enough. Any idea why?

Comment: If you change tabs and a component is rerendered, it should not loose its state. When the text in comment field is cleared, probably means the component has unmounted and mounted again; State has changed to initial value which is probably an empty string. I'm not sure what's going on in your code. But you probably can reproduce the same issue without using `react-activity-feed` library in a codesandbox. Unless `react-activity-feed` is doing something unusual. In that case you could search for similar issues in their github(?).

Answer (score 0):

Consider wrapping your parameter-component in `useCallback`:

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';

// ...

          Activity={useCallback((props) => {
            console.log(
              " ~ file: [activityId].js ~ line 52 ~ PostDetails ~ props",
              props
            );
            return (
              <Activity
               // ... props to Activity
              />
            // ...
          }, [Activity, ...])}
```

See the react documentation for [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

Comment: I've actually used `useMemo` and passed `[props.activity]` in the second arg. It keeps being re-rendered even though `props.activity` did not change! (checked using JSON diff checker) It only stopped re-rendering when I passed `[props.activity.id]` which is not enough. Any idea why?

Comment: @Eric Yes, you have to know that when JS uses a shallow comparison for object. If the JSON you get is stable, you can try passing `[JSON.stringify(props.activity)]` in the second argument. It should stop re-renders.